# How to generate a unique plist for a project when it is based on a previous project in Unity

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, build, plist

I've been working on a new Mac app based on (copied from) an old Unity project. I have renamed the new project at the folder level, and have changed the 'Product Name' in 'Player Settings'. But when I build the app on the same computer that the old app was built on, the new app opens already populated with the information stored in the plist for the old app.

I want to have both apps working on the same computer, but now having used the new program on the same computer as the old, it has wiped the plist information from the old program and replaced it.

How do I force the app to use a unique PlayerPrefs plist? (Hopefully without having to rebuild the project from scratch!)

Answer (score 0):

According to the API on MacOs in the editor `PlayerPrefs` uses a path based on the `bundleIdentifier`

> **In-Editor Play mode storage location**
>
> On macOS, PlayerPrefs are stored in `/Library/Preferences/[bundle identifier].plist`.

=> Try to change the bundle identifier in the [PlayerSettings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlayerSettings-macOS.html#AppStore)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had already tried this, didn't fix it. What I had to end up doing was a build for Xcode and changing my code signing - but I don't know why this worked.